# How do i to store input in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch file with choices. I use:

```
ERRORLEVEL 
or 
set /P c=Choose..
if /I "%c%" EQU "1" goto :place1
```

What I can't figure out is - how to keep choice input for later. If I input 32, then I want to store it for later use, like:

```
start batchfile32
```

Batchfile is always the same, `start Batchfile&%choice%` is enough. The syntax for this eludes me however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried? Because this seems to works:

```
set /P c=Choose..
start Batchfile%c%
```

Gives output:

```
Choose..32
The system cannot find the file Batchfile32.
```

**Edit:** Of course I do not have a file named `Batchfile32`, but the system is trying to start it. Showing that the variable is used correctly.

Comment: Aw so it automatically records it... Wouldn't have figure it out soon. I thought i have to use some derivative of choice. (I'm not a coder in case the comment is silly :)

Answer (score 0):

**check.bat**

```
set /p ck=
start sample%ck%
```

**sample5.bat**

```
calc
```

**output**

```
5
```

a calc will be open if user input is 5

Comment: Ty too, tough hebron nailed it first (:

Comment: That's ok but you got a solution :)